# What's the fastest way to create a 'throw away' SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server

For my acceptance tests, the first thing they do is create a bunch of tables in a test-specific SQL Server database, so that the acceptance tests can run against a clean database. When each test is finished, all the newly created tables are dropped.

However, this is starting to get slow. Each test takes around 15 seconds, and I have quite a lot of them (and I expect the number to keep going up). Most of the time is taken up by database set up & tear down.

Is there a faster way I can do this? if I could create a new SQL Server database in-memory, so it never hits the disk, that I can throw away at the end of the test - that would be great. But seeing as that isn't really an option, is there a way I can get close to that?

Comment: Use a mock or a stub database?

Comment: I am using mocks for some of the unit tests, but I want the acceptance tests to talk to a real database of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already managing a script or scripts in version control of your complete database DDL so that you can create a new database, right?  :)  If not, do that first.  It will pay off for more than just testing.

Now that you have scripts maintained in version control, just use your preferred scripting environment to dynamically create a database, and populate it with the required test data, prior to actually running your test suite.  If you're on .NET, you could use NANT or something like that.  In the Java world, use Maven or Ant (or Maven AND Ant).  If you're in Rails, try it with Capistrano or just a Ruby script.  In other words, it just depends.  Regardless of that, the main thing is to just create your database creation scripts, maintain them, and use them to build your test databases on demand, and tear them down when you're done (or when you re-run the scripts).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the features you use in SQL Server but I believe [SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=033cfb76-5382-44fb-bc7e-b3c8174832e2) could be useful - if it supports all the features you use.

I have spent a while on finding best ways to do database unit testing and back a few years ago, attaching a SQL Server was a solution I came up with but that was time-consuming and clunky.

In a recent project I started using SQlite for a project I was using an ORM (nhibernate) but had to abandon it because I needed stored procs.

---

### UPDATE

[This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140%28SQL.110%29.aspx) will tell you if you can use SQL Server CE or not.

### It is very limited So it is unlikely you could use to for all your tests.

Comment: That's probably quite a big "If" isn't it?

Comment: Well, if your project is domain-driven (and not data driven) and you are using ORM and use database as a repository, then you do not need full-fledged db.

Comment: Yes, I checked and seems to be a lot less than what I thought. Not even `ORDER BY`!

Comment: I think that might just mean `ORDER BY` column ordinal rather than named column? I guess the OP can just try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is 12 years too late, but today you can use various open source framework such as [ThrowawayDb](https://github.com/Zaid-Ajaj/ThrowawayDb).

Answer (score 0):

I thought SQL server supported cursors, anyway. Easiest way to junk the contents of a table would be `drop table <name>`, or `truncate table <name>` if you're just trying to empty it.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are acceptance tests, not unit tests, I would probably try to construct them so that each subsequent test is either independent (with respect to the data) or builds upon the data from previous tests, with the tests being run in a deterministic sequence.  That way you can build the database once and clean it up when all tests have completed.  For unit tests, I would certainly look at mocking out the database layer so that your tests never hit the actual database.